Where is the 'voltage control' when using the LM13700 as a Voltage Controlled Resistor
Looking at the application notes for the LM13700 and the VCR application TI Data Sheet - See page 15, the output resistance \$R_X\$ is given by: \$R_X = R + R_A / g_m . R_A\$ . Notably, there is no control voltage in this equation that would influence \$R_X\$.
My (likely limited) understanding of VCRs is that an input control voltage will vary the resistance between two output terminals.  For the LM13700, am I misunderstanding their application circuits described as VCRs (i.e. there is some voltage control input point I am missing), or are these application notes describing a circuit for which there is no voltage control over the output resistance (yet still referred to as VCR)?
I'm very much an amateur hobbyist, so I may be missing the totally obvious!
Thanks for any help.

VC is the control voltage. The text just before the diagram explains the gm term:
"where gm ≈ 19.2IABC at 25°C. Note that the attenuation of VO by R and RA is necessary to maintain VIN within the linear range of the LM13700 input."
